# Automating a test case in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to automate a test case in robot framework in which we are trying go to this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all and write a query in query editor. I am not able to do write query in query editor. Please help and thanks in advance.

```
*** Test Cases ***
query
    Open Browser    https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all    gc
    Input Text    //*[@id="tryitform"]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre[1]    Select * from tests
```

[image]

I guess i have to use some different keyword instead of "Input text" .

Comment: You trying to input "SELECT * FROM tests" into the textarea within the W3Schools tutorial?

Comment: What happens when you run your test? Do you get errors? Are you certain that the xpath is correct? is the input widget inside a frame? What else have you tried?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am getting  error " InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it."

Comment: Have you done any research into that error? Error messages exist for a purpose: to give you hints as to what's wrong. At the time that I write this comment there are 25 questions on stackoverflow that mention this error message. Do none of them help you?

Comment: @Goralight This is like query editor, where we can run our query online.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes i did some research. But still not able to fix it. Because this is not normal text area and i guess i have to use some other Keyword instead of Input text.

Comment: @Ishanmahajan I'm not following... You have your own query editor - but you're using the W3Schools one? Also, the reason why you're getting that error is because you are trying to input text into a element which can't handle text being inputted to it...

Comment: @BryanOakley Hi Bryan i am trying to do same thing in ace Editor, can you please guide me how you find codemirrror variable name(window.editor in this case) so that i can do the same thing there.

Comment: You won't find the codemirror variable in an application using ace. Ace doesn't use codemirror.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know. Actually i want to interact with ace editor(same way as we did here) how can i achieve that.

Comment: I guess you start by reading some ace documentation.

Comment: @BryanOakley Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that the text area isn't a standard html textarea widget. It is a [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/) editor, and I don't think you can directly interact with the codemirror editor using selenium commands.

What you can do instead is use the codemirror api to set the value in the editor. For example, the following works for me on the web page specified in your code example:

```
Execute javascript     window.editor.setValue('Select * from tests')
```

Note: this solution is *highly dependent* on the web page implementation. In this specific case, the web page is creating a javascript variable named `window.editor` which refers to the codemirror object. If you are trying to do this on some other page that uses codemirror, you might have to use some other method to get a reference to the codemirror object.